# How to make parent selector interpolated in the middle of nested selector in sass/scss

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to get the result below using sass nesting

## css

```
.box {...}
h3.box-title {...}
```

I tried code like this, but it causes an error.

## sass

```
.box {
    h3.&-title {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is any way to do this keeping sass nesting?

I know that it's not good to write HTML element on CSS,
but I'm working on a project that I can't modify existing CSS and need to overwrite them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.box {
    @at-root h3#{&}-title {
        ...
    }
}
```

I **used the sass interpolation `#{}` to compile expectedly the value of `&`**, and **`@at-root` to prevent the prefix `.box`** *(prevent resulting to `.box h3.box-title` because we want `h3.box-title` only - without the prefix `.box`)*

Here's the captured result:
[image]

Anyway, **I don't think this is a good practice to write sass/scss**

Comment: It worked perfectly.
I'm more than happy and thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.box
```

and

```
.box-title
```

are two different class names. Unless h3.box-title is a child of .box, honestly, there's no reason you should be nesting it.

Also & is used to look for additional class names.  i.e.

```
.box {
 &.box-title {} 
}
```

would be

```
.box.box-title {}
```